# How to log stdout output in Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j

Is there a way to log all stdout output to the catalina.log file in Tomcat? (i.e. everything that gets printed to `System.out.println()`)

The console window that opens when you run `TOMCAT/bin/startup.bat` displays output from stdout, but it's not saved to `TOMCAT/logs/catalina.<date>.log`.

My specific problem is that I have a console appender defined in log4j to output to the console.  These log messages appear correctly in the Tomcat console window, but they are not written to catalina.log.  I'm running Tomcat 5.5 on Windows.  Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Here is my log4j.properties file.  It is located at `TOMCAT/webapps/app/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties`:

```
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p %c{1}]: %m%n
```

Comment: Does tomcat log to catalina.log, when you start it as a windows service instead of using startup bat?

Comment: @Gandalf I don't know.  I don't want to run it as a service.

Comment: Where do you have log4j configured with console appender? Per web application or on tomcat itself?

Comment: @Gandalf It's in my web application.  So it's located at: `TOMCAT/webapps/app/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties`

Comment: @Gandalf Tomcat seems to use java.util.logging...is it possible that log4j is not compatible?

Comment: I don't think so, but I am not exactly sure in this case. We also use log4j together with tomcat 5 and it works like a charm but we never use console appenders but rolling file appenders. Have you tested only with debug log or also with error? Maybe tomcat is configured with a threshold for file output.

Answer (score 11):

I've come across similar questions before, and haven't found a way to do this by logging System.out in Windows [unless you are running Tomcat as a Windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142650/tomcat-logging-using-log4j). This seems to work by default in Unix since `startup.sh` points to `catalina.sh` which logs stdout to the `catalina.out` file like below

```
org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap "$@" start >> "$CATALINA_BASE"/logs/catalina.out 2>&1 &
```

In log4j, `ConsoleAppender` by itself does not append to a File, only to    `System.out`

However, I've modified your log4j properties to add a FileAppender and this config works, but of course this logs into a separate log file.

New config

```
# Set root logger level to DEBUG.
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, console, myFile

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p %c{1}]: %m%n




# myFile writes to file
log4j.appender.myFile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.myFile.File=logs/tomcatlog4j.log
log4j.appender.myFile.MaxFileSize=100KB
log4j.appender.myFile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.myFile.layout.ConversionPattern==[%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p %c{1}]: %m%n
```

Output

> =[15:24:03,819 INFO  A1]: In my.jsp
>   =[15:24:03,975 INFO  A1]: Out of my.jsp
>   =[15:24:04,880 INFO  A1]: In my.jsp
>   =[15:24:04,880 INFO  A1]: Out of my.jsp

also see

[How to log exceptions from a specific package deployed in tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215148/how-to-log-exceptions-from-a-specific-package-deployed-in-tomcat)

[log select events into a separate file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241689/log-select-events-into-a-separate-file)

https://serverfault.com/questions/201178/tomcat-5-5-how-to-redirect-the-logging-output-to-one-file-per-web-application

Comment: So you're saying on Linux, a ConsoleAppender would write to catalina.out, but on Windows it doesn't unless Tomcat is run as a service?

Comment: @Michael: I can confirm ConsoleAppender **does** write to `catalina.out` on Linux. I've tested this.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I just wanted to make sure I understood what you where saying.  So it sounds like the answer to my question is, "No, ConsoleAppender will only write to catalina.log on Windows if Tomcat is run as a service"

Answer (score 1):

Did you checked, whether the log4j.properties file can be found from your application?
Maybe you can check, by setting a hardcoded file path like

> -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///C:\Dev\log4j.properties

If the logs are written after these change, the relativ path to the log4j file is wrong.

Comment: It's in the root of my classpath.  So it's located at: `TOMCAT/webapps/app/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties`.

Answer (score 1):

If I look at the default logging config of tomcat 5.5 in logging.properties:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
```

That looks to me as if stdout of web applications might be logged to files only for level INFO and above, regading that http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/logging.html states that in tomcat JULI logging configuration loggers do not use parent's handlers when they are assigned their own handlers. Also the file should be prefixed `localhost` and not `catalina`. But then I do not understand how the output comes to your output window :/

Comment: Thanks.  I tried changing all those levels from "INFO" to "DEBUG", but none of the stdout output appears in any of the log files (catalina, localhost, manager, or host-manager).  I'll have to read that link in more detail.